# Global minimum of a parameteric function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $q:[1, + \infty) \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad q(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{lcl}
\delta_{1} & \text{ if } & 1 \leq x < \epsilon_{2} \\
\vdots & & \\
\delta_{n-1} & \text{ if } & \epsilon_{n-1} \leq x < \epsilon_{n} \\
\delta_{n} & \text{ if } & \epsilon_{n} \geq x
\end{array} \right .
$

for a given partition $[1, \epsilon_{2}),\dots ,[\epsilon_{n-1}, \epsilon_{n}), [\epsilon_{n}, +\infty)$ of its domain, and $1 >\delta_{1} \geq \delta_{2}\geq ... \geq \delta_{n} > 0$. Fix an integer $t\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, and consider the function

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad l : [1, t]\subset \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \longmapsto \frac{1}{1-q^{x}\left (\frac{t}{x} \right)}\left ( 1 + \sum_{j = 1}^{\lfloor \frac{t}{x} \rfloor - 1} q^{x}(j) \right)$

with the convention that the summatory cancels out for $\lfloor\frac{t}{x}\rfloor - 1 < 1$. My problem is to study the trend and find global minima on the domain $[1, t]$. The function is clearly not globally continuous, in its generic form. Would it make sense to study the derivative in this context?

This is a complicated problem, and I do not expect a full answer. However, any hint on how to proceed analytically would be greatly appreciated. In the context I a working, a good approximation or reduction to a simpler similar problem would be ok.

Comment: Instead of using all those `\qquad`s to indent your equations, use the MathJax display format: `$$`...`$$` instead of `$`...`$`. Your equations will automatically indent as needed and they also will look better.

Comment: Why do you have deleted this question ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787904/discrete-cumulative-distribution-inequality

Comment: On second thought, I realized it might have been to obvious

Answer (score 1):

The derivative can help you see what is happening in each interval.  Is the function increasing or decreasing there?  Does it have a local minimum on the interval?  If so, this might be a candidate for the global minimum.

Then you also want to see what happens at the discontinuities.  Does the function jump up or down?